# GA does not support RegEx

Tags: regex, performance

I am using the following RegEx (check on different RegEx checkers online, on which it works):

```
^((?!pro).)*$
```

However, GA gives me an error: Invalid regular expression
Your data request includes an invalid regular expression.

The line I am trying to exclude is: `xx-pro-xxx-xxx`

I have read through the documentation Google provides, but cannot seem to find why it is not working.

Does anybody know what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: You can't write a pattern that does not contain a multicharacter string in RE2 compliant regex. Use a negative filter with a mere `pro` as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GA doesn't seem to support lookeheads](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en) (`(?!...)`), so you can't use that regex. Maybe there is a way to use `.{2}-pro-.{3}-.{2}` in a negative condition, i.e. "don't use strings that match this pattern"?

General advice - every regex engine is different and supports different set of operators. It's not enough to check regex on other engines